# ( Solved ) How to join "@joinTable" using QueryDSL

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I want to get the SQL to join `Summoner`, `summoner_match` and `match` using JPASQLQuery class.
like this.

```
SELECT
    *, row_number()OVER()
FROM 
    summoner s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    summoner_match sm
on
   s.account_id= sm.account_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    match m
on
   sm.game_id = m.game_id
```

I add my source code below.

```
package gg.om.omgg.domain.summoner;

import gg.om.omgg.domain.match.Match;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Summoner implements Serializable {
    @Id@Column(length=56)
    private String id;
    @Column(name="account_id", length=56)
    private String accountId;
    private int profileIconId;
    private long revisionDate;
    private String name;
    @Column(length=78)
    private String puuid;
    private long summonerLevel;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="summoner_match",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="account_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="game_id")
    )
    private List<Match> matches = new ArrayList<>();

    //...
}
```

```
package gg.om.omgg.domain.match;

import gg.om.omgg.domain.participant.Participant;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Match {
    @Id
    @Column(name="game_id")
    private long gameId;
    private int queueId;
    private String platformId;
    private int seasonId;
    private long gameCreation;
    private long gameDuration;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", referencedColumnName = "game_id")
    List<Participant> participants = new ArrayList<>();

    //...
}
```

.
.
.
Seems to have found a way.
I will be an advisor.

```
package gg.om.omgg.domain.summoner;

import com.querydsl.core.Tuple;
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory;
import com.querydsl.jpa.sql.JPASQLQuery;
import com.querydsl.sql.SQLExpressions;
import gg.om.omgg.domain.match.QMatch;
import gg.om.omgg.domain.participant.QParticipant;
import gg.om.omgg.web.dto.SummonerIntegrationInformationResponseDTO;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SummonerCustomRepositoryImpl implements SummonerCustomRepository {
    // JPASQLQuery class is registered as @Bean in advance
    private final JPASQLQuery jpasqlQuery;
    @Override
    public void mySolution() {
        QSummoner summoner = QSummoner.summoner;
        QMatch match = QMatch.match;
        // Create Qclass for @JoinTable
        QSummoner summoner_match1 = new QSummoner("summoner_match");
        QMatch summoner_match2 = new QMatch("summoner_match");

        jpasqlQuery
        .select(summoner, match, SQLExpressions.rowNumber().over())
        .from(summoner)                                                                                              
        .leftJoin(summoner_match1)
        .on(summoner.accountId.eq(summoner_match1.accountId))
        .leftJoin(match).on(summoner_match2.gameId.eq(match.gameId))
        .fetch();
   }
}
```

Comment: I got an answer on [github](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2809)

Please refer.

Comment: After read the answer in github, I cannot understand why `JPASQLFunctions` doesn't provide and very usual use case like a many to many table.

Comment: I have included an answer in a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241737/join-a-many-to-many-relation-with-querydsl-and-jpasqlquery), adding another solution to the provided one in your `github` link.